# $A,B$ closed subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ , when can we say (other than compact-ness of $A$ or $B$ ) $\exists b \in B$ such that $dist(A,B)=dist(b,A)$ ?

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity, normed-spaces

Let $A,B$ be disjoint closed subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ , when can we say ( weaker than compact-ness of $A$ or $B$ ) that there exist $b \in B$ such that $dist(A,B)=dist(b,A)$ ? I know that if $A,B$ are subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ such that $B$ is compact , then there does exist $b \in B$ such that $dist(A,B)=dist(b,A)$ , but I am looking for a weaker restriction on $A$ or $B$ than compactness . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you will find a more useful condition than "it holds when it holds".  There won't be anything as simple as compactness; you can easily find pairs of closed sets $(A,B), (A', B')$ such that it holds for $A,B$ and doesn't hold for $A',B'$, yet the two pairs of sets are topologically very similar.

Comment: @NateEldredge : I thought so , but is it not even possible to get a weaker restriction when we stick just to $\mathbb R^n$ with standard metric ?